# Need to Store record on Delete Action

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trigger, lightning

I need a sample code for a custom object which can store records from another object where records are getting deleted (on click of delete button) 
for example: i have 'xyz' object and their is a record name 'abc' which i am going to delete than this 'abc' object gets stored in another custom object 'wxy' before going into recycle bin as i want to create a separate records of deleted record..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is some good documentation to guide you.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm#!)

Also try a [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) if you are stuck.

```
trigger SomeTriggerName on SomeCustomObject__c (Before Delete) {

  if (trigger.isDelete && trigger.isBefore) {

    List<NewCustomObject__c> newObj = new List<NewCustomObject__c>();

    for (SomeCustomObject__c obj : Trigger.old) {
      // Instantiate new object
      // Map fields from deleting object to new object
      // Add new obj to list
    }

    insert list;
    delete oldObj;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach you can write before delete trigger. Let us consider we have two custom object as cObj1 and cObj2 and whenever anyone is deleting record from cObj1, you can map the fields from cObj1 to cObj2 in trigger and insert a new record in cObj2. So everytime it will create new record in cObj2.